# Unity3D Android - Move your character to a specific x position

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, position

Im making a new game for android and I wanted to move my character (which is a cube for now) to a specific x location (on top of a flying floor/ground thingy) but I've been having some troubles with it.I've been using this script :

```
var jumpSpeed: float = 3.5;
var distToGround: float;

function Start(){
// get the distance to ground
distToGround = collider.bounds.extents.y;
}

function IsGrounded(): boolean {
return Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector3.up, distToGround + 0.1);
}

function Update () {

// Move the object to the right relative to the camera 1 unit/second.
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime);

if (Input.anyKeyDown && IsGrounded()){
rigidbody.velocity.x = jumpSpeed;

}
}
```

And this is the result (which is not what I want) :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fj8B6eI4dbE&feature=youtu.be

Anyone has any idea how to do this ? Im new in unity and scripting.Im using java btw.

Ty.

Answer (score 0):

I may not be understanding your question right, but here is what I think you want.

I think that you want the player to jump straight up, so here is the code for that:

```
if (Input.anyKeyDown && IsGrounded()) {
    rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpSpeed, ForceMode.Impulse);
}
```

If you do want the player to jump to the right (as is in the video) you can change the "up" in Vector3.up to whatever direction you want (i.e. right, left, down).

If this doesn't help, could you provide some more details on what the desired behavior is?